# MS Access set shortcut to fields and combo boxes

Tags: ms-access

In MS Access I can set a shortcut key to a button using the &-Ampersand symbol in the caption, is there a way to get focus of a field or dropdown in the same way so for example if I have the field First Name I and press Alt+F to enter that field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the shortcut to the label and it will work for the field.